# Pause and changing timer value of running timeout function in a recursion

Tags: javascript

I have tried a lot of thing like codding timer class, callback functions etc. but I have never success.

My code:

```
function paint(node, direction, color, isB) {

        var treePoint = document.getElementById(node.obj.circleId);

        i++;

        timeStack.push(setTimeout(function () {
            paint2(node, direction, color, isB, treePoint);
        }, timer * i));

        i++;

        timeStack.push(setTimeout(function () {
            paint3(node, direction, color, treePoint);
        }, timer * i));
    }
}
```

I calling this function several time in a recursive function like:

```
function recursion(...){
    //do something
    if(condition){
        paint(...)
        recursion();
    )
    //do something
    paint(...)
    //do something
    paint(...)
    //...
    //...
    if(condition)
        recursion();
}
```

The code running perfectly but I need to add pause button and change the timer value with a range input. I have tried some solutions but the solutions are not for recursion. I think the code are already run just waiting for timer. I need to access and change the timer value after running via pause button. Is it possible?

By the way the `timeStack.push()` part to keep timer ids to clearTimeouts for stop button and my stop button is working well.

Comment: You can't edit the `setTimeout` parameters after you have set them in js. What you could do is stop every time and set up new once with the new params as you change them.

Comment: But the problem is I am painting different place every single step. I could pause with cleartimeout function but couldn't resume in no way. Maybe there is different solution other than changing timer.